# Make thin shared library

Tags: gcc, g++, shared-libraries, ghc, elf

I have a plenty of `lib*.a` files, which origins from *GHC* Haskell project. Only symbols I needed are:

```
extern "C" void init();
extern "C" void show();
extern "C" void hide();
extern "C" void close();
```

There are a plenty of undefined symbols (I sure it is Haskell-specific) (a part of `CMakeLists.txt`):

```
list(APPEND LINKER_UNDEF "-Wl,-u,hs_atomic_or8")
list(APPEND LINKER_UNDEF "-Wl,-u,hs_atomic_or16")
list(APPEND LINKER_UNDEF "-Wl,-u,hs_atomic_or32")
list(APPEND LINKER_UNDEF "-Wl,-u,hs_atomic_or64")
list(APPEND LINKER_UNDEF "-Wl,-u,hs_atomic_xor8")
list(APPEND LINKER_UNDEF "-Wl,-u,hs_atomic_xor16")
list(APPEND LINKER_UNDEF "-Wl,-u,hs_atomic_xor32")
list(APPEND LINKER_UNDEF "-Wl,-u,hs_atomic_xor64")
... # plenty of them
```

If the Haskell project is standalone application its size is about 5MB, but sum of sizes of `lib*.a` files is about 70MB.

I want to make `lib*.so` file of minimal size. This means I only need symbols on which `init`, `show`, `hide`, `close` depends. If I use `-Wl,--whole-archive`, then all symbols exported by `*.o` files from `*.a` files would be included into resulting shared library `*.so` file. But how to make linker to include only required symbols (maybe plus `main` symbol from ad-hoc `*.c` file, if can't be omitted)? Can I build ELF file, which is ambivalent: it is `*.so` file and simple ELF executable at the same moment? Can I achieve this using `-rdynamic` option?

Answer (score 2):

> how to make linker to include only required symbols

Linker does that when linking against static libraries: it only includes those object files that resolve currently unresolved symbols.

When linking a shared library it must export all symbols with external linkage (unless you use a custom linker script) because the information about actually used symbols is unavailable at this point in time.

If you want to minimize the total size of your application files link statically to avoid shipping unused code, that otherwise would be present in shared libraries.